# EntityFramework + ASP WebAPI + SelfReference model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am writing Simple database project using Entity Framework and ASP WebAPI.

I'm fighting with creating a model, which has Self-Reference.

Like:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
}
```

I have created API, and I would like to create new ProductCategory or, if this is possible, whole reference path of categories ex:

- Category 1

  - Category 1.1

    - Category 1.1.1

Additionally, when I'm going to help page, it shows error `Object graph for type contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.`

To fix that i have found that I need to add `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` to `ProductCategory` class, but I still don't know how to use POST to create new object(object graph)

Could somebody help me with that?

EDIT:
For now, I have tried even simple POST method (with CategoryName) like:

```
{
    "CategoryName":"test"
}
```

but this returns 500 error:

`Project.Models.ProductCategory_ParentCategory: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential constraint in Role 'ProductCategory_ParentCategory_Target' in relationship 'ProductCategory_ParentCategory'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.`

`ProductCategory_ParentCategory_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ProductCategory_ParentCategory_Source' in relationship 'ProductCategory_ParentCategory'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'`

Same problem is whe I'm trying to define other properties. But it should work with clear "CategoryName" property set.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck/why didn't your code work? Post your code.

Comment: you can see it in edit

Comment: If you use Entity framework, why don't you use ADO.NET entity Data model. It will create all the necessary classes for you. the only thing you have to take care of is you database.

Comment: I am using Code First, so I do care about code, and do not care about database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set up a nullable foreign key because the relationship EF is infering by convention implies every record has a parent which is obviously impossible as some item has to be the root.  Try the following:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentCategory")]
    public int? ParentCategoryId {get;set;}

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
}
```